# Chrome & Firefox don't remember user session

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

For some reason my Chrome & Firefox browser are not remembering user sessions for firebase.

When I login to my application in localhost and refresh the page nothing happens. However in Safari when I login and refresh it automatically logs in again.

I have checked my Chrome settings and these seem to be alright, additionally I experience the same behaviour in Firefox with default settings.

**Update**
After doing some more checks, Firefox it does not work on localhost (127...) but it does work deployed, and in Chrome it doesn't work at all. Also did a reinstall of Chrome which did not seem to fix it.

**Update2** Here is a video that shows the behaviour on a deployed website in Chrome:

```html
<iframe src="https://embed.cl.ly/dd6a3c880bd1" width="575" height="400" style="border:none" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" allowfullscreen="true"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 2):

Check chrome settings? 
I think you might've accidentally disabled web storage under content settings.

Comment: I have checked my storage settings and nothing appears to be off - additionally i experience the same issue in Firefox.